# ChartJs - stacked bar chart with groups - how to create second x-axis with stack id

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart.js grouped bar chart (grouped by the stack id), what I want to do, is **add another x-axis**, which will show the **stack id**, the closest I got was doubling the labels, so `["1.1.2021", "2.1.2021"]` was changed to `["1.1.2021", "1.1.2021", "2.1.2021", "2.1.2021"]` - this didnt work well, the x-axis didnt align properly and the visuals were off.

Here is what I currently have:

```js
var ctx = $("#c");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["1.1.2021", "2.1.2021"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'First Time Visitor England',
      data: [10, 3],
      stack: "first-time-visitors",
      backgroundColor: "#f5a0a7",
    },
    {
      label: 'Repeating Visitors England',
      data: [20, 6],
      stack: "repeat-visitors",
      backgroundColor: "#e75177",
    },
    {
      label: 'First Time Visitor Sweden',
      data: [7, 0],
      stack: "first-time-visitors",
      backgroundColor: "#924565",
    },
    {
      label: 'Repeating Visitors Sweden',
      data: [9, 16],
      stack: "repeat-visitors",
      backgroundColor: "#2979a7",
    }]
  },
  options:{
    scales:{
      xAxes:[
        {
          stacked: true,
          id:'xAxis1',
          type:"category",
          ticks:{
            callback:function(label){
              var month = label.split(";")[0];
              var year = label.split(";")[1];
              return month;
            }
          }
        }],
      yAxes:[{
        ticks:{
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

and I want to have another x-axis, above the date axis, which will show the stack id, so two ticks above 1.1.2021 - first is labeled `first-time-visitors`, and the second `repeat-visitors` (this will also repeat for the 1.2.2021).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have the additional labels aligned with the stack group bars, you can define the option `categoryPercentage: 1` on each `dataset`.

> For further information, consult the chapters [Dataset Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration) and [barPercentage vs categoryPercentage](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage) of the Chart.js bar documentation.

Further you'll have to define several x-axes as shown in your amended code below.

```js
new Chart('c', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["1.1.2021", "2.1.2021"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'First Time Visitor England',
        data: [10, 3],
        stack: "first-time-visitors",
        backgroundColor: "#f5a0a7",
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'Repeating Visitors England',
        data: [20, 6],
        stack: "repeat-visitors",
        backgroundColor: "#e75177",
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'First Time Visitor Sweden',
        data: [7, 0],
        stack: "first-time-visitors",
        backgroundColor: "#924565",
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'Repeating Visitors Sweden',
        data: [9, 16],
        stack: "repeat-visitors",
        backgroundColor: "#2979a7",
        categoryPercentage: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'x'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'category',
          offset: true,
          labels: ['first-time-visitors', 'repeat-visitors', 'first-time-visitors', 'repeat-visitors'],
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          }
        },
        {
          offset: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```