# Plot nested dicts in Chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I'm fairly new in js and I'm using chartjs to plot information of database.
Until now, I have managed to plot all my work. But there is one thing I don't know how to do.

I have a nested dict like this :

```
{
    "tech_1": {
        "cert_1": 1,
        "cert_2": 3
    },
    "tech_2": {
        "cert_3": 10,
        "cert_4": 5
    }
}
```

How can I plot this dict in chartJS to have something like this :

[image: plotting nested dict chartjs]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67515923/2358409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.js doesn't support nested label.
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4946

In discussion above, unofficial plugin is recommeded. This may realize your needs.
https://github.com/sgratzl/chartjs-plugin-hierarchical